# Reusable Beautiful Soup Parser/Config?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a Selenium-based web crawler application that monitors over 100 different medical publications, with more being added regularly. Each of these publications has a different site structure, so I've tried to make the web crawler as general and re-usable as possible (especially because this is intended for use by other colleagues). For each crawler, the user specifies a list of regex URL patterns that the crawler is allowed to crawl. From there, the crawler will grab any links found as well as specified sections of the HTML. This has been useful in downloading large amounts of content in a fraction of the time it would take to do manually.

I'm now trying to figure out a way to generate custom reports based on the HTML of a certain page. For example, when crawling X site, export a JSON file that shows the number of issues on the page, the name of each issue, the number of articles under each issue, then the title and author names of each of those articles. The page I'll use as an example and test case is https://www.paediatrieschweiz.ch/zeitschriften/

I've created a list comprehension that produces my desired output.

```
url = "https://www.paediatrieschweiz.ch/zeitschriften/"
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

report = [{
    'Issue': (unit.find('p', {'class': 'section__spitzmarke'}).text).strip(), 
    'Articles': [{
        'Title': ((article.find('h3', {'class': 'teaser__title'}).text).strip()),
        'Author': ((article.find('p', {'class': 'teaser__authors'}).text).strip())
    } for article in unit.find_all('article')]} 
    for unit in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'section__inner'})]
```

Sample JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "Issue": "Paediatrica Vol. 33-3/2022",
        "Articles": [
            {
                "Title": "Editorial",
                "Author": "Daniela Kaiser, Florian Schaub"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Interview mit Dr. med. Germann Clenin",
                "Author": "Florian Schaub, Daniela Kaiser"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Ern\u00e4hrung f\u00fcr sportliche Kinder und Jugendliche",
                "Author": "Simone Reber"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Diabetes und Sport",
                "Author": "Paolo Tonella"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Asthma und Belastung",
                "Author": "Isabelle Rochat"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Sport bei Kindern und Jugendlichen mit rheumatischer Erkrankung",
                "Author": "Daniela Kaiser"
            },
            {
                "Title": "H\u00e4mophilie und Sport",
                "Author": "Denise Etzweiler, Manuela Albisetti"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Apophysen - die Achillesferse junger Sportler",
                "Author": "Florian Schaub"
            },
            {
                "Title": "R\u00fcckenschmerzen bei Athleten im Wachstumsalter",
                "Author": "Markus Renggli"
            },
            {
                "Title": "COVID-19 bei jugendlichen AthletenInnen: Diagnose und Return to Sports",
                "Author": "Susi Kriemler, Jannos Siaplaouras, Holger F\u00f6rster, Christine Joisten"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Schutz von Kindern und Jugendlichen im Sport",
                "Author": "Daniela Kaiser"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Issue": "Paediatrica Vol. 33-2/2022",
        "Articles": [
            {
                "Title": "Editorial",
                "Author": "Caroline Schnider, Jean-Cristoph Caubet"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Der prim\u00e4re Immundefekt \u2013 Ein praktischer Leitfaden f\u00fcr den Kinderarzt",
                "Author": "Tiphaine Arlabosse, Katerina Theodoropoulou, Fabio Candotti"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Arzneimittelallergien bei Kindern: was sollten Kinder\u00e4rzte wissen?",
                "Author": "Felicitas Bellutti Enders, Mich\u00e8le Roth, Samuel Roethlisberger"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Orale Immuntherapie bei Nahrungsmittelallergien im Kindesalter",
                "Author": "Yannick Perrin, Caroline Roduit"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Autoimmunit\u00e4t in der P\u00e4diatrie: \u00dcberlegungen der p\u00e4diatrischen Rheumatologie",
                "Author": "Florence A. Aeschlimann, Raffaella Carlomagno"
```

However, if possible I'd like to avoid using a custom Python statement or function for each individual crawler, as each would require different code. Each crawler has it's own JSON config file which specifies the start URL, allowed URL patterns, desired content to download, etc.

My initial idea was to create a JSON config to specify the Beautiful Soup elements to scrape and store in a dictionary - something that a colleague who does not write code would be able to set up. My idea was something like this...

```
{
    "name": "Paedriactia",
    "unit": {
        "selector": {
            "name": "div",
            "attrs": {"class": "section__inner"},
            "find_all": true
        }, 
        "items": {
            "issue": {
                "name": "p", "attrs": {"class": "section__spitzmarke"}, "get_text": true
            } 
        }, 
        "subunits": {
            "articles": {
                "selector": {
                    "name": "article",
                    "find_all": true
                },
                "items": {
                    "Title": {
                        "name": "h3",
                        "attrs": {"class": "teaser__title"},
                        "get_text": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...along with a Python function that would be able to parse the HTML according to the config and produce a JSON output.

However, I'm at a total loss as to how to do this, especially when it comes to handling nested elements. Each time I've tried to approach this on my own I've totally confused myself and have ended up back at the start.

If any of this makese sense, would anyone have any advice or idea of how to approach this sort of Beautiful Soup config?

I'm also fairly proficient in writing code with Beautiful Soup, so I'm open to the idea of writing custom Beautiful Soup functions and statements for each crawler (and perhaps even training others to do the same). If I take this route, where would be the best place to store all of that custom code and import it? Would I be able to have some sort of "parse.py" file in each crawler folder and import its function only as needed (I.e., when that specific crawler is run?)

If helpful, an example of the current structure of the web crawler projects is below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With BeautifulSoup, I strongly prefer [using `select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and `select_one` to using `find_all` and `find` when scraping nested elements. (If you're not used to working with CSS selectors, I find the [w3schools reference page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to be a good cheatsheet for them.)

If you defined a function like

```py
def getSoupData(mSoup, dataStruct, maxDepth=None, curDepth=0):
    if type(dataStruct) != dict:
        # so selector/targetAttr can also be sent as a single string 
        if str(dataStruct).startswith('"ta":'):
            dKey = 'targetAttr'
        else:
            dKey = 'cssSelector'
        dataStruct = str(dataStruct).replace('"ta":', '', 1)
        dataStruct = {dKey: dataStruct}

    # default values: isList=False, items={}
    isList = dataStruct['isList'] if 'isList' in dataStruct else False
    if 'items' in dataStruct and type(dataStruct['items']) == dict:
        items = dataStruct['items']
    else: items = {}

    # no selector -> just use the input directly
    if 'cssSelector' not in dataStruct:
        soup = mSoup if type(mSoup) == list else [mSoup]
    else:
        soup = mSoup.select(dataStruct['cssSelector'])
        # so that unneeded parts are not processed:
        if not isList: soup = soup[:1]

    # return empty nothing was selected
    if not soup: return [] if isList else None

    # return text or attribute values - no more recursion
    if items == {}:
        if 'targetAttr' in dataStruct:
            targetAttr = dataStruct['targetAttr']
        else:
            targetAttr = '"text"'  # default

        if targetAttr == '"text"':
            sData = [s.get_text(strip=True) for s in soup]
        # can put in more options with elif
        else:
            sData = [s.get(targetAttr) for s in soup]

        return sData if isList else sData[0]

    # return error - recursion limited
    if maxDepth is not None and curDepth > maxDepth:
        return {
            'errorMsg': f'Maximum [{maxDepth}] exceeded at depth={curDepth}'
        }

    # recursively get items
    sData = [dict([(i, getSoupData(
        s, items[i], maxDepth, curDepth + 1
    )) for i in items]) for s in soup]

    return sData if isList else sData[0]
    # return list only if isList is set
```

you can make your data structure as nested as your html structure [because the function is recursive]....if you want that for some reason; but also, you can set `maxDepth` to limit how nested it can get - if you don't want to set any limits, you can get rid of both `maxDepth` and `curDepth` as well as any parts involving them.

Then, you can make your config file something like

```json
{
    "name": "Paedriactia",
    "data_structure": {
        "cssSelector": "div.section__inner",
        "items": {
            "Issue": "p.section__spitzmarke",
            "Articles": {
                "cssSelector": "article",
                "items": {
                    "Title": "h3.teaser__title",
                    "Author": "p.teaser__authors" 
                },
                "isList": true
            }
        },
        "isList": true
    }
    "url": "https://www.paediatrieschweiz.ch/zeitschriften/"
}
```

[`"isList": true` here is equivalent to your `"find_all": true`; and your "subunits" are also defined as "items" here - the function can differentiate based on the structure/dataType.]

Now the same data that you showed [at the beginning of your question] can be extracted with

```py
# import json
configC = json.load(open('crawlerConfig_paedriactia.json', 'r'))

url = configC['url']
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

dStruct = configC['data_structure']
getSoupData(soup, dStruct)
```

For this example, you could add the article links by adding `{"cssSelector": "a.teaser__inner", "targetAttr": "href"}` as `...Articles.items.Link`.

Also, note that [because of the defaults set at the beginning in the function], `"Title": "h3.teaser__title"` is the same as

```json
"Title": { "cssSelector": "h3.teaser__title" }
```

and

```json
"Link": "\"ta\":href"
```

would be the same as

```json
"Link": {"targetAttr": "href"}
```

Comment: this is fantastic and exactly what I was trying to get at. I have tested this out and achieves the intended output, I will test out a few other scenarios. In the meantime I'm still trying to understand the function code for myself. I really appreciate this help!

Comment: Glad to help! (BTW, if it helps understand the function's code quicker : just focus on the lines with `sData` first- those are the essential bits; the rest are just setting defaults to make parts of the config format optional, and some error handling.)